# Где ошибка кода - не работает функция "loginUser"

Tags: php

Опишу ситуацию в 4 этапа. Функция "emptyInputLogin" работает корректно. Подключение к базе тоже работает.

1. `login.php`

   ```
    <?php
        include_once 'header.php';
    ?>
    <section class="signup-form">
        <h1>Log in</h1>
        <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/email">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
                if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
                    echo "<p>Fill all</p>";
                }
                elseif ($_GET["error"] == "wronglogin") {
                    echo "<p>In correct log in</p>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </section>
    <?php
        include_once 'footer.php';
    ?>
   ```
2. `login.inc.php`

   ```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $username = $_POST["uid"];
        $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

        include_once 'db.inc.php';
        include_once 'function.inc.php';

        if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
            header("location: ../login.php?error=emptyinput");
            exit();
        }

        loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd);

    } else {
        header('location: ../login.php');
        exit();
    }
   ```
3. `function.inc.php` - функция `loginUser()`

   ```
    function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd) {
        $uidExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

        if ($uidExists === false) {
            header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
            exit();
        }

        $pwdHashed = $uidExists["usersPwd"];
        $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

        if ($checkPwd === false) {
            header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin")
            exit();
        }
        elseif ($checkPwd === true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $uidExists['userId'];
            $_SESSION['useruid'] = $uidExists['usersUid'];
            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
   ```
4. `function.inc.php` - функция `uidExists()`

   ```
    function uidExists($conn, $username, $email) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersUid = ? OR usersEmail = ?;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
        // запуск запроса
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
            return $row;
        }
        else {
            $result = false;
            return $result;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
   ```

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код текстом, а не картинками!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите весь код в виде **отформатированного** текста (как в IDE)

Comment: И напишите, что значит "не работает функция “loginUser”". У каждого этого своё значение. Оно абстрактное))

Comment: Мои сильные рекомендации: **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482) и [Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**

Comment: Опишите подробней проблему. Как вы поняли, что функция не работает? Что она должна сделать и что она по итогу сделала.

Comment: @Павел-Ериков функция должна выдать ошибку ввода данных или войти, но страница зависает на login.inc.php выдав ошибку "Страница недоступна"

Comment: как минимум в файле пропишите `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` и посмотрите ошибки

Comment: По урокам Дани Кроссинга пытаешься учиться? Брось бяку. Это игровой видеостример, он пхп не знает от слова "совсем". А по поводу ошибки - у тебя точно есть страница login.inc.php в папке **includes**?

Comment: @Ипатьев да есть. как то жалко столько времени уже просмотрел и взять остановится на этом месте. дойду уже до конца. )

Comment: Ну тогда не надо бегать тут с вопросами, почему не работает. по определению. потому что код изначально кривой. Этот дятел делает всё, чтобы ты никогда не узнал, в чем проблема

Comment: @Ипатьев почему на русских платформах злые ребята всегда сидят...)  америкоты хоть и туповаты но не быдловаты. спасибо)

Comment: Да, это разница менталитетов. У русских принято говорить как есть, например что этот Кроссинг - дурак и самозванец. А в америке принято пичкать тебя bullshit sandwich-ем - даже если ты конкретно облажался, то все равно сначала надо похвалить, потом мельком упомянуть твой эпик фейл в варианте "ну вот тут я бы не стал вырезать пациенту гланды через зад автогеном, а помазал бы зеленкой", и потом обязательно снова похвалить. И поэтому считается что русские "злые".

Comment: @Ипатьев у тебя есть уроки? php

Comment: Всё никак не соберусь. Но по крайней мере лучше учить по [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners). Тоже не без изъянов, но Джеффри, в отличие от Кроссинга, хотя бы понимает что делает. Кроссинг реально идиот который как обезьяна повторяет за другими, не понимая смысла. Вот то что ты учишь: [40 строчек кода](https://phpize.online/?phpses=1588f05e27b72ddcc685c77577bb6fbe) на два несчастных SQL запроса.  А вот этот же код [здорового человека](https://phpize.online/?phpses=43c31f94f1c8271bd481f19109e5740a). А потом мы удивляемся - почему многие считают РНР языком для тормозов.

Comment: Можешь конкретнее описать, как выглядит "Страница недоступна"? Обычно такая ошибка вообще не связана с кодом. Это скорее какая-то ошибка конфигурации сервера, например он не принимает пост запросы. Надо посмотреть на этот запрос в консоли разработчика, какой код возвращает сервер. И в логах веб-сервера что пишет.

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за совет.

касательно ошибки url останавливается на http://localhost/phpsitetest/includes/login.inc.php 

Страница недоступна
Сайт localhost пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Прекрасно. HTTP ERROR 500 - вот ключевая строчка, которая всё проясняет. Это ошибка в коде. чтобы её увидеть надо либо включить вывод ошибок на экран, либо посмотреть в логе веб-сервераю. в общем вот можно посмотреть   краткие но ёмкие рекомендации:  http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо дружище! ссылка помогла.
нашел с помощью
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

точку с запятой не проставил в функции loginUser()